# aspNetHidden div not being served depending on client

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

I am developing a C# app that gets web pages and processes their contents line by line. To do this, I use the `HttpClient` class, and read the page contents through `ReadAsStreamAsync()`. Then I read the stream into a line array and iterate over it. So far so good.

However, the HTML that I obtain with this method is not identical to the HTML that I observe if I navigate to the web page using Chrome or Edge and use View Source to get to the HTML. In particular, the __VIEWSTATE and __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR hidden `input` elements are surrounded by `div` elements with `class="aspNetHidden"` when I use the browser, but not when I get the HTML programmatically. This ruins my line tracking logic as there are extra lines in the page as seen by the browser in relation to the page I am getting in code.

**EDIT**. After some testing, I am confident that the user agent header employed by the client is what determines whether or not the `class="aspNetHidden"` `div` is served. When I mimic my browser's user agent ("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36 Edg/83.0.478.37"), the `div` is served; if I use some other agent such as "Test Client", the `div` is not served.

My question then is, is there any documentation on what user agent strings cause the `div` to be served and which don't? Also, can I prevent this from happening?

Thanks.

Comment: There may be a script which gets executed onload of the html and changes the html content. It may not be necessary that the HTML you are seeing on the browser (view source) should match with the one that you read using HttpClient.

Comment: How are you parsing the html? If you use something like [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) the amount of lines should not matter.

Comment: @VDWWD: I am not parsing the HTML, but doing some line-oriented processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, it is not documented/specified in terms of useragents, but browser capabilities.

Based on the browsers useragent a set of capabilities gets set up.
These capabilities are configured in `.browser` configuration files on the webserver.
For e.g. `.NET 4` you find these files in `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\browsers`,
e.g. `chrome.browser`, `iphone.browser`, etc.

Such a `.browser` file contains a `tagwriter` capability.
E.g. `chrome.browser`:

```
<browsers>
    <!-- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/530.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/2.0.168.0 Safari/530.1 -->
    <browser id="Chrome" parentID="WebKit">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Chrome/(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(\.(?'minor'\d+)?)\w*)" />
        </identification>

        <capabilities>
          <capability name="browser"   value="Chrome" />
          <capability name="tagwriter" value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />

          <!-- ... -->  
        </capabilities>
    </browser>
</browsers>
```

The `tagwriter` capability specifies whether  a `System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter` or a `System.Web.UI.Html32TextWriter` will be be instantiated to write the output.

The default configuration in the `Default.browser` file, declares `tagwriter` as:

```
<capability name="tagwriter" value="System.Web.UI.Html32TextWriter" />
```

Also, if the `tagwriter` capability is missing a `Html32TextWriter` is being used.
From the [Microsoft reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Configuration/HttpCapabilitiesBase.cs,191):

```
internal HtmlTextWriter CreateHtmlTextWriterInternal(TextWriter tw) {
    Type tagWriter = TagWriter;
    if (tagWriter != null) {
        return Page.CreateHtmlTextWriterFromType(tw, tagWriter);
    }

    // Fall back to Html 3.2
    return new Html32TextWriter(tw);
}
```

The `Html32TextWriter` declares not to render a `div` around hidden input fields.
From the [Microsoft reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/Html32TextWriter.cs,86):

```
internal override bool RenderDivAroundHiddenInputs {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The `HtmlTextWriter` does return `true` for `RenderDivAroundHiddenInputs`,
see the [Microsoft reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/HTMLTextWriter.cs,24).

Some more reading about all this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/january/the-asp-column-determining-browser-capabilities-in-asp-net).

---

What you can do.

If you always want the wrapping `div`, use one of the wellknown useragents, otherwise use a custom one like the `Test Client` you are already using.
If you control the website being requested, you can set up a custom `.browser` file for your custom useragent ... *but I would rather not go that way* ...

When making the request, just set the appropriate `User-Agent` request header on your `HttpClient`, e.g.:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var userAgent = "Test Client"; // Or "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36 Edg/83.0.478.37"
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", userAgent);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can happen for a number of reasons one of most likely ones is the one that [@thangadurai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1363011/thangadurai) mentioned `There may be a script which gets executed onload of the html and changes the html content.`. This could be avoided by using a UI testing framework such as Selenium or using headless Chrome programmatically.

One of the other possible reasons is the `User-Agent` dependant implementation. This can be simply solved by changing the `User-Agent` header.

**EDIT:** If you control the webpage you could probably disable ViewState if that's the case. The behavior might be based on detecting the `User-Agent` capabilities. For your processing, you could go with either string and make it static when you send the request, though it might not be as reliable. Another method to the processing without parsing could be using a regular expression to match specific tags. The specifics of the deciding on rendering ViewState were nicely described by @pfx [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62146287/4965962).

Comment: Thank you. I will check this and get back to you.

Comment: I've checked the pages thoroughly and it doesn't seem to be any scripts that can alter the HTML.

Comment: I've also checked the agent, and this works. I am updating my question accordingly. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: added an edit with possible solutions, also referred to @pfx answer as he described the specifics of the rendering a bit better. I hope this solves your problem.